# Symfony collections with children

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

maybe somebody know how used in template twig, collection form with children collection type.

For example Quiz , have question collection type and question have answer collection type..

```
$builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('questions', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => QuestionType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype'    => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'prototype_name' => 'name',
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
        ])


 $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('numberCorrectAnswers', NumberType::class)
            ->add('answer', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => AnswerType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype'    => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'prototype_name' => 'name',
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            ])
        ;
```

and answer form type have some text fields. How it implement in twig?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special you need to know .. first create your form type like you did with Collection Typ.

And then in Twig:

```
        {% for answer in form.questions.answer %}
            <div class="col-md-3">{{ form_row(answer) }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
```